# Mysql Error Code 1265: Data truncated for column after increasing varchar column size

Tags: mysql

I have a varchar column in a table that was varchar(1000) and was increased to varchar(6000).  After updating this table, I get this error mentioned when trying to update a specific row in the table.

This row has a string currently with length of 647 characters (no special characters in there, just alphanumeric and $ symbol in the string).

If I try to update it like:
`update TradeEntries set DataValue = 'test' where ID = 16632;`

I get the error:
Error Code: 1265. Data truncated for column 'DataValue' at row 1

If I try:
`delete from TradeEntries where ID = 16632;`

I also get the same error:
Error Code: 1265. Data truncated for column 'DataValue' at row 1

Do you know what could be wrong and how I can fix this?  I can't edit or delete this row anymore.  The current value in this row for DataValue is:
`orderNo$TRUE,eoOrderIdorderNo$TRUE,eoOrderId$TRUE,orderStatusId,oldOrderId$TRUE,chainOrderNo$TRUE,equityOptionInd,orderTypeCode,accountType$TRUE,repID,status,tradeAction,lplAcct,acctName,securityID,quantity,stopPrice,conditions$TRUE,timeInForce,acctType,orderType,clientName,orderDate,canEdit,canEditAction$TRUE,canCancel,canCancelAction$TRUE,totalRecords,accountID,clientID,originCode$TRUE,securityNo,actionCode$TRUE,updateSource$TRUE,errorResponse$TRUE,closingTriggerPrice$TRUE,orderStatusId,oldOrderId$TRUE,chainOrderNo$TRUE,equityOptionInd,orderTypeCode,accountType$TRUE,repID,status,tradeAction,lplAcct,acctName,securityID,quantity,stopPrice,conditions$TRUE,timeInForce,acctType,orderType,clientName,orderDate,canEdit,canEditAction$TRUE,canCancel,canCancelAction$TRUE,totalRecords,accountID,clientID,originCode$TRUE,securityNo,actionCode$TRUE,updateSource$TRUE,errorResponse$TRUE,closingTriggerPrice$TRUE`

Answer (score 0):

This was due to a trigger that was now affected by the larger column change.  Adjusted the column length in the table the trigger was inserting into and resolved it.